# Barbecue Barcode PDF417

Tags: pdf417, barbecue

I need to generate a PDF417 barcode with error correction level of 5 using Barbecue api.

I generate a PDF417 by calling createPDF417(data) on the BarcodeFactory and this returns a barcode object which is passed to my print formatting class as a ByteArrayOutputStream, but I'm struggling to see how/if it implements any error correction level and if i can set this anywhere. I can see methods in the PDF417Module class (createCodeWords and generateEC) that look like what i'm expecting.  I just cant see how the draw method in the PDF417Module class is actually called.

I apologise, I'm a relative novice.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a weekend off and done some drinking and some sleeping and now I see the PDF417Module is instantiated and the method called.  I now feel embarrassed for asking.